# Developer/Tools/sdp: No such file or directory

Tags: xcode

I am working to make my application apple scriptable,for which i use the developer material in the link [here](https://developer.apple.com/cocoa/applescriptforapps.html)

That tutorial take CircleView Application for example, and make it into an apple Scriptable application through some procedural steps.

While following that steps,after a new run script has been added in CircleView Application as said in the tutorial , i got error

```
Developer/Tools/sdp: No such file or directory
```

I don't know how to solve

Comment: `/Developer` is now obsolete with recent versions of Xcode in favour of `Xcode.app` within the `/Applications` (or `~/Applications`) folder.  You will need to find what the `sdp` program is called and whether it's available for recent versions of Xcode.  Have you tried to find it within `Xcode.app`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an error that was complaining there was no `/usr/bin/sdp`

I found the file in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/sdp` and fixed the error with:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/sdp"
```

Which created a symlink to where `sdp` was installed. I installed Xcode via the AppStore and so I'm not sure why this file / symlink was not created in the first place, but this fixed my problems.